# How to insert a string infront of a line with regex?

Tags: regex

given

```
line one
this is line two and so on
```

How can this be made to be

```
"line one
"this is line two and so on
```

The best I can figure is `/^[a-z.]{1}/` but matching then replacing would get rid of the first letter of each line and it does not cover all characters. How can this be fixed.

ps What is a good place to learn regex.

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is redundant.)

Comment: You may find these helpful: [(guide)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) [(analyzer)](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws) [(tester)](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not replace the beginning-of-line marker with something?  I don't know what language/library you're using, but this works on the Linux command line:

```
echo "line one" | sed -e 's/^/"/'
```

Comment: So if I was editing a file called test would the command be `sed -e 's/^/"/'  w even test`?

Comment: auser: I'd do `cat test | sed -s 's/^/"/'`

Comment: `cat test | sed -s 's/^/"/'` prints to the console the correct result but it does not save it to the file.

Comment: `sed 's/^/"/' test > testout` worked but I still don't know how to edit the original file

Comment: sed isn't designed for editing a file; it's designed for editing a stream.  If you want to use sed, one strategy would be to replace the input file with the output file after sed completes.  For instance, `sed 's/^/"/' test > testout && mv testout test`

Answer (score 1):

Replace function overwrite current value with new value.
learn regex http://regexone.com/
and http://www.regexr.com/

Regex Solution in java:

```
    String myline = "line one";
    Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$");
    Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher(myline);
    if (mymatcher.matches()) myline = ( "\""+mymatcher.group(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try match for the `^`, i.e. start of the string, and replace it with the character you need.

Comment: Trying to match and replace using ^ did not do anything.